# Object is altered during serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

i am trying to serialize my object, however when i deserialize everything is set to null. I must be missing something, please help.
Here is the serialize part:

```
public static void write(Map<String, Allat> m){
  try {
      FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("savefile.txt");
      ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
      //m has the correct parameters at this point
      out.writeObject(m);
      out.close();
      fileOut.close();
  }
  catch(IOException i) {
      i.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("Success.");
}
```

Here is the deserialize part:

```
public static Map<String, Allat> read(String path) {
    Map<String, Allat> m;
      try {
          FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);
          ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
          m = (Map<String, Allat>) in.readObject();
          in.close();
          fileIn.close();
      }
      catch(IOException i) {
          System.out.println("IO Exception");
          i.printStackTrace();
          return null;
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
          System.out.println("Allat class not found");
          c.printStackTrace();
          return null;
      }
      return m;
}
```

After calling the read method, everything in the resulting object is set to null/0.
The "Allat" class does implement java.io.Serializable. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried serializing a single object instead of an entire map? does this work?

Comment: no... it doesnt work with a single object either.

Comment: If so could you please provide a minimal example in order for us to reproduce the exact problem? I mean including Allat class and a main method to see how you actually run the program.

Comment: I suggest you ignored an exception somewhere. NB If you get `ClassNotFoundException` it isn't necessarily the `Allat` class that wasn't found. Don't make assumptions of any kind in error messages. Use the one that came with the exception: don't make up your own.